# Regex to match words containing dots?

Tags: regex

Let's say I want to match urls that might contain a dot.

The parser I'm using has a "url contains" feature, so if I type "you" it'll match "youtube.com/blahblah" and any other URL containing "you".

However, if I use "youtube", it'll match "youtube.com" but not "youtu.be".

So for example, if I wanted to match apple, banana, app.le, banan.a, and ba.nana, but not orange or ora.nge, what would I have to add to (apple|banana) to match those words containing dots anywhere in them?

Comment: `(app\.?le|banan\.?a|ba\.nana)`

Comment: I'd try turning the problem around a bit rather then looking to solve it directly with a regex. Strip dots, then do the regex. Obviously this will depend on your exact situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to match optional dots between every pair of letters:

```
(a\.?p\.?p\.?l\.?e|b\.?a\.?n\.?a\.?n\.?a)
```

Although this would allow any number of dots. To limit the number of dots to maximum 1, add a negative look ahead:

```
(?!.*?\..*?\.)(a\.?p\.?p\.?l\.?e|b\.?a\.?n\.?a\.?n\.?a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(y(|\.)o(|\.)u(|\.)t(|\.)u(|\.)b(|\.)e)
```